# How to generate vaadin components dynamically into vaadin view

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have very new requirement that I need to know we can achieve that with vaadin or not.

My team members already developed one functionality using jquery and jsp along with spring as backend. Suddenly, vaadin came into picture to develop UI.

***Functionality:***
Admin has the full access to all the modules. Admin user can add components from a pool of components to some other module. These settings can be saved into db. Later when I tried to access that module. Only those components(Admin selected components) should be available to me. In this case one jsp is automatically created with the admin selected components and that will be included into another jsp which is a user jsp.

My question is can vaadin fulfill this requirement?

Comment: How do concern your question title and your question descritption (*may be my poor English*) ? I I can't imagine what is your problem. Do you mean **Authentication , Authorization** or **role-base UIs** ?

Comment: @Cataclysm My question is not about Authentication, Authorization or role-base. Its about "Can the server create and return Vaadin components to the client?" Sorry for my poor english

Comment: I found similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007389/how-to-create-ui-dynamically-server-side-with-gwt-2-4 here. There someone suggested with vaadin we can achieve this. I dont know how to do that.

Comment: I would like to suggest to check about [vaadin's Architecture](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/architecture.html) . GWT is client-side , Vaadin is server-side. So , DB results are on your hand and Vaadin's components also in server-side. What should you do ? Please check [Integrating with the Server-Side](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.html) for create custom components.

Comment: I am not asking about custom components. for example: I have 2 views. one view is user view, another is appointment view. First admin will log into application. Then he will be in user view class. There will be one checkbox(If he checks that, the selected components will be flown to that view(appointment)) There is one dropdown box with all the field names(checkbox,textbox,..ect). As soon as he selects one component from dropdown, that component will be created automatically and added to the view(appointment view) at run time. Like this, he can select any component any number of times

Comment: Would you like to do as [Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/) does ?

Comment: Yes exactly, But in case of tiles those header, footer and body should be available already in order to include in main jsp. But here component(ex: textbox) should be created automatically and flown to the another view

Answer (score 1):

Create one UI class (*in GWT similar with EntryPoint*) and create header , footer , leftside , rightside etc;
 And create Views as you want (for instance: userView , adminView). Add your default view in body content of UI class . Initialize Navigator for page navigation. When url was change or invoke by some request , navigator should manage relative body contents. Please check [Usage of UI vs. Navigator+Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20214763/vaadin-7-usage-of-ui-vs-navigatorviews) for further UI , Views and Navigation.

Here is [example](http://askvikrant.com/vaadin-7-for-beginners-part-2/) and [sample codes](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9upYsG402GCT1ZRaWRQMTNtVlE/edit). If you want to create as component , [composition](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/components.customcomponent.html) is a way.